# Flattening XML with XQuery

Tags: function, xquery

I am trying to flatten an XML hierarchy to the text nodes where the output tag names are the hyphen concatenated tags on the path of each text node.  I amusing the sample XML provided at http://www.chilkatsoft.com/xml-samples/bookstore.xml as input.

So far I have created this XQuery:

```
declare function local:flatten($prefix as xs:string*, $nodes as node()*) as node()*
{
    for $node in $nodes
    return
        typeswitch($node)
            case element() return
                local:flatten(insert-before($prefix, 1, $node/name()), $node/node())
            case text() return
                element {string-join(fn:reverse($prefix), '-')} {string($node)}
            default return
                'oops'      
}; 

for $b in //bookstore/book return 
    local:flatten((), $b)
```

This mostly works but the output looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
</book>
<book-title>The Iliad and The Odyssey</book-title>
<book>
</book>
<book-price>12.95</book-price>
<book>
</book>
<book-comments>
</book-comments>
<book-comments-userComment> Best translation I've read. </book-comments-userComment>
<book-comments>
</book-comments>
<book-comments-userComment> I like other versions better. </book-comments-userComment>
<book-comments>
</book-comments>
<book>
</book>
...
```

I don't care about the lack of a root element at this time (one step at a time) but I don't want the spurious empty parent tags between the correctly rendered text nodes.  What am I doing wrong?
I am very new to XQuery and may have made a silly error.

Comment: Check your data. I ran your code against the document sample you provided, and the empty book elements are not returned.

Comment: You don't need a function to flatten and collect the element names, you could also use `for $book in bookstore/book, $text in $book//text()[normalize-space()] return element { string-join(($text/ancestor-or-self::* except $book/ancestor::*)/name(), '-') } { data($text) }`, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhi

Comment: @MartinHonnen That is indeed neater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XQuery processor is treating the boundary whitespace between elements like `<book>` and `<title>` as text nodes. To discard these in your query, you would need to modify the element case in your typeswitch as follows:

```
case text() return
    if (normalize-space($node) eq "") then 
        ()
    else 
        element {string-join(fn:reverse($prefix), '-')} {string($node)}
```

Comment: That is perfect.  Thank you.